# How can I visualise Reddit's XML-schema in XVCG or Dotty?

Tags: xml, dependencies

You can find the [schema](http://code.reddit.com/browser/config/solr/schema.xml?rev=1456a12c3446c6d13fa3c38272af701bdc91060e). So how can I visualise it to see dependencies, packages and such things?

Comment: Try XSD DIAGRAM at http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about XVCG or Dotty, but it seems what you're trying to do is reverse-engineer an XML file into some form of UML diagram. There are a bunch of options you can take, varying between paid and free -- the paid options tend to work a lot faster and may allow better exporting unless of course you don't mind coding something to do the job.

***Disclaimer:*** I have no affiliation with the below, I have purely used them before in different use cases.

1. [Oxygen XML](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_editor.html): Provides a simple IDE with which to edit and view XML schema. Can export to different formats (from which you can transport over to Dotty/XVCG?)
2. [DTDChart](http://www.intsysr.com/dtdchart.htm): A shareware/freeware app which takes in any DTD format and transforms it into a relative chart/diagram. Fairly simple to use to get output but doesn't provide any real export functionality other than the diagram.
3. [hyperModel](http://www.xmlmodeling.com/hypermodel/overview/): An Eclipse plug-in, can take most good XML DTD and turn it into a relevant UML diagram. From there you can save it in various interoperable UML formats, e.g. IBM Architect, MagicDraw.
4. [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.xmlschema.info/xml_schema_editor.html): Load up an XML Schema and format it for different viewing formats.
5. Research papers on converting XML to UML should you wish to create your own tool to do the job: [Reverse Engineering of XML Schemas to Conceptual Diagrams](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV96Necasky.pdf), [Reverse engineering XML documents into DTD Graph with SAX](http://www.sftw.umac.mo/~robertb/publications/WSEAS2006/WSEAS2006.pdf) and [XMI](http://xml.coverpages.org/xmi.html).

I have personally found Altova XMLSpy and Oxygen XML to give me the best results. However you may wish to create your own parser to complete your task.